# How do I test grunt task callback with nodeunit?

Tags: node.js, callback, gruntjs, nodeunit

I have a nodeunit test that tests my custom grunt task:

```
'use strict';

var grunt = require('grunt');

exports.when_executing_single_command = {
    it_should_execute_successfully: function(test) {
        test.expect(1);

        grunt.initConfig({
            mytask: {
                success: function(data) {
                    test.strictEqual(data, '1');
                    test.done();
                }
            }
        });
        require('../src/mytask')(grunt);
        grunt.registerTask('default', ['mytask']);
        grunt.task.run('default');
    }
};
```

Based on [nodeunit documentation](https://github.com/caolan/nodeunit#usage) the test appears to be setup correctly, but the callback is never executed and test continues to run indefinitely.

I know that under the right conditions the callback is definitely executed, so this is not a bug in my task.

Answer (score 1):

Exact same issue here.

It appears to me that grunt is queuing task calls. So if you launch your tests with a grunt nodeunit command you cannot launch another task inside your test, it will be queued and can only be run after your nodeunit task is done.

There is a solution but it doesn't fit for my case, it may apply for you :

```
grunt.util.spawn({
   grunt: true,
   args: ["your_task_name"],
   opts:{
      stdio: 'inherit'
   }
}, function(){
   // Do something
})
```

[grunt.util.spawn](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.util)

Comment: Thanks J2AN. Can't test my solution right now (I'm on holiday), but +1 posting your answer :-)